# TYPO3 typoscript if condition based on site language

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

My typo3 version is 11.5.10.
I have two footer images, one for German and one for English .
I want to render different image for different language.
I tried this way for German language.

```
[siteLanguage("locale") == "de_DE"]
   50 = COA
      50 {
        wrap = <div class="footer__item col-sm-6 col-md-3 img-custom">|</div>  
        stdWrap {
          typolink {
            parameter = {$myconstant.footer-logo-link-4}
            parameter.noTrimWrap = || _blank|
          }
        }

        50 = IMAGE
        50 {
          file = user_uploads/german-footer.png

          layoutKey = srcset
          layout.srcset {
            element = <img WIDTH###" SOURCECOLLECTION###" ###PARAMS### ###ALTPARAMS### ###SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>              }
        }
      }
[end]
```

And for English language.

```
[siteLanguage("locale") == "en_US"]
   50 = COA
      50 {
            wrap = <div class="footer__item col-sm-6 col-md-3 img-custom">|</div>  
            stdWrap {
              typolink {
                parameter = {$myconstant.footer-logo-link-5}
                parameter.noTrimWrap = || _blank|
              }
            }

            50 = IMAGE
            50 {
              file = user_uploads/english-footer.png

              layoutKey = srcset
              layout.srcset {
                element = <img WIDTH###" SOURCECOLLECTION###" ###PARAMS### ###ALTPARAMS### ###SELFCLOSINGTAGSLASH###>              }
            }
          }
    [end]
```

In both language FE i get English-footer.
I also tried Different function of siteLanguage like

1. siteLanguage("navigationTitle")
2. siteLanguage("locale")
3. siteLanguage("hreflang")  etc..

What i am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

I get the following error in Typoscript Object Browser

Errors and warnings
Warning : Line 5696: Object Name String, "[siteLanguage" contains invalid character "[". Must be alphanumeric or one of: "_:-/." Show details

Warning : Line 5718: Object Name String, "[END]" contains invalid character "[". Must be alphanumeric or one of: "_:-/." Show details

Warning : Line 5719: Object Name String, "[siteLanguage" contains invalid character "[". Must be alphanumeric or one of: "_:-/." Show details

Warning : Line 5741: Object Name String, "[END]" contains invalid character "[". Must be alphanumeric or one of: "_:-/." Show details

Comment: The TypoScript Object Browser is struggling, because of missing closing braces... Your snippets are opening 5 braces, but only closing 4 of them.
A cleaner indention would show this ;)

Comment: @JulianHofmann Sorry, but i mistake in write question on this. In my file braces are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid conditions whenever possible. Conditions are evil!

Conditions are checked for each and every page request - before any cached content is touched. extensive use of conditions will be a performance killer.

For more details, search for "typo3 condition performance"

### Using TypoScript `if`

A better way would be using the [`if`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/If.html)-function, which is cachable, in combination with *getText* [`siteLanguage`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/DataTypes/Properties/GetText.html?highlight=sitelanguage#sitelanguage).

```
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.data = siteLanguage:languageId
page.10.stdWrap.wrap = <p>siteLanguage:languageId=|</p>

page.20 = IMAGE
page.20 {
  if.value = 1
  if.equals.data = siteLanguage:languageId
  file = EXT:example/Resources/Public/typo3_package_de.png
}

page.30 = IMAGE
page.30 {
  if.value = 0
  if.equals.data = siteLanguage:languageId
  file = EXT:example/Resources/Public/typo3_package_en.png
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same problem with Typo3 10.x.

In your Typoscript, as you write 50 = ... you're probably in a curly braces such as page.
This is not valid : Conditions can not be nested within curly braces.

You can check there : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/TypoScript/Syntax/Conditions/Index.html#typoscript-syntax-conditions#id5